# Updating nested data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can i update values inside of `discussionReplay` object. The `trio`, `comment`, `commentImg` and the `commentOwner`.
User.findOne method return the user now i need to find the right `discussion` with matching `discussionsId` and update the `discussionReplay` inside the corresponding `discussion`.

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    discussions: [{
        title: String,
        discussionsId: String,
        discussionReplay: {
            comment: String,
            commentImg: String,
            commentOwner: String
        }
    }]
});

const comment = req.body.comment;
const userId = req.body.UserId;

User.findOne({ discussions: { $elemMatch: { discussionsId: req.params.id } } }, function (err, theUser) {
    theUser.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, function (err, data) {
        data.discussions: {
            $elemMatch: { discussionsId: req.body.id },
            { $push: { comment: comment, commentImg: "/location/...", commentOwner: 'username' } }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Why findByIdAndUpdate instead of just modifying theUser and saving it?

Comment: I tried but i just couldn't do it. and i ended up with this code. It would be awesome if i could directly update it.

Comment: Did you do theUser.save() after?

Comment: Thank Jim. I did exactly what you said. findbyid and .save method. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi Jim. .save method bringed another issue to the database. Encrypted passwords gets encrypted again after save method. Noone can log in anymore. Any idea for this?

Comment: I see.  You must have some other middleware/plugin that does the password encryption automatically on save.  I usually don't do that, and only encrypt the password on user registration.  Not sure what to suggest without knowing how you manage passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify the object you get back from find() and call it's .save() method after.

```
User.findOne({<criteria>}).then(theUser => {
    theUser.property.subpropertyarray.push(<new value>);
    return theUser.save();
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17701817)

Comment: You mean I didn't phrase it as a piece of code?  I'll edit.

Comment: .save method bringed another issue to the database. Encrypted passwords gets encrypted again after save method. Noone can log in anymore. Any idea for this?  Update methods do not recreate the user schema.And i try not to change the layout of the database. Should i avoid .save method.. or i am confused at the mo

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. This doesn't refresh the whole user Schema like .save methos, so passwords aren't being encrypted again.

```js
var toInsert =  {comment: "someComment", commentOwnerName: 'someName'};
                                          User.update(
                                          { _id: req.body.userId, discussions: { $elemMatch: { discussionsId: req.params.id } } },
                                          { $addToSet: { 'discussions.$.discussionReplay': toInsert } }, function(){})
```